# Why does typed address operator not apply when taking the address of a string element?

Tags: delphi

This program

```
{$T+}

var
  PA: PAnsiChar;
  PW: PWideChar;
  s: string;

begin
  PA := @s[1];
  PW := @s[1];
end.
```

compiles. I would expect that with `{$T+}` that one of the assignments would have been rejected by the compiler. In modern Unicode Delphi I would expect the first assignment to be invalid.

The documentation for [type-checked pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)#Type-checked_Pointers) says:

> When `@` is applied to a variable reference in the `{$T+}` state, the type of the result is `^T`, where `T` is compatible only with pointers to the type of the variable.

Why does using typed addresses not seem to apply to the code above?

Comment: Because of type or assignment compatibility: [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi))

Comment: I can't find that a reason either, see [Type Compatibility & Assignment Compatibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi)#Type_Compatibility). None of the type compatibility rules apply and none of the assignment compatibility rules as well.

Comment: Interestingly, when you replace the string s with a char c the compiler complains as expected.

Comment: Even more interesting is that if you replace s[1] with s[2] in both places it again complains as expected!

Comment: @Dsm, that is the usual error message with all those pointer type mismatches. It only mentions the required result type generalizing the source type.

Comment: @UweRaabe OK, comment removed.

Comment: @Dsm Oh, that is really quite something!

Comment: It's clearly a bug.  The whole point of `PChar` and `PAnsiChar` is to manage null-terminated strings.  Unicode strings are naturally full of single null bytes so `PA := @s[1];` can't represent anything but corruption.  As for why it fails, `{$T+}` manages declared pointer types, but `PChar` and `PAnsiChar` are never declared anywhere as `^Char` and `^AnsiChar` - they are strictly internal types so the compiler must naturally have independent internal handling for these that is different from its general handling of pointer types.  It would seem this is a bug in that handling.

Comment: Consider also an explicit type `EPChar = ^Char;` and variable `epc : EPChar;`.  For a string `s`, the assignment `s := epc` is not valid but `s := PW` is valid -- this only to make the point that `PChar <> ^Char`, so the function of `{T+}` doesn't necessarily apply.  That said, a type `EPAnsiChar = ^AnsiChar` with var `epac : EPAnsiChar` still wrongly compiles with the assignment `epac := @s[1]` (and fails with `epac := @s[2]`.  In any case, it's still a mishandling of these internal types.